# Como y para que funcionan los parametros?

Tags: javascript

Como funciona esta `función` y principalmente sus `parámetros`?

```
(function(window, document){

})(window, document);
```

Se que es una `funcion anonima` y que se **autoejecuta**, pero no se como recibe y ***para que se podrían utilizar*** sus `parametros`

Y *si se supone* que las funciones que se ***autoejecutan(IIFE)***, se **ejecutan de forma inmediata**, entonces recibiria `undefined` ? porque la `IIFE` se ejecuta **antes** que el `documento`? o el `IIFE` **espera** al `documento`?

Answer (score 6):

#### no se como recibe y para que se podrían utilizar sus parámetros

Los parámetros se los estas pasando tú. La **invocación** de la función está indicada por el uso de los paréntesis `XXX( )`. De no tenerlos, **no quieres ejecutarla**, sino obtener dicha *una referencia* a la función, que no es lo mismo.

En el caso que expones

```
(function(window, document){

})(window, document);
```

1. Creas un objeto, que es una función. En JS, **todo** son objetos. La palabra reservada `function` indica el tipo de objeto.
2. Lo anterior **devuelve** (en JS, **toda** expresión devuelve algo) un objeto `function`.
3. Un objeto `function` **seguido** de paréntesis, implica la **ejecución** de dicha función, a la que se envian los argumentos contenidos entre los paréntesis.

Una vez *ejecutando* la función, los parámetros serán usados como dicha función determine o necesite.

En el ejemplo expuesto, los argumentos pasados son, respectivamente, `window` y `document`. El valor de estos **depende del contexto en el que crees y ejecutes la función**. Si estas en el ámbito principal, fuera de cualquier otra función, dichos argumentos serán el objeto global `window`, y el objeto `window.document`. Recordemos que, si hacemos referencia a una variable y no es posible encontrarla en el ámbito actual, se buscará como *miembro* del objeto global `window`.

***EDITO***

Las expresiones *IIFE* se ejecutan dependiendo de las opciones usadas al *cargarlas*, como cualquier otro código. Si están dentro de módulos llamados mediante `<script src=XXX>`, dependerá de `defer` y `asyc`.

En cualquier caso, la ejecución se realiza **en estricto orden de aparición** dentro de su archivo fuente. Si está en el `index.html`, se ejecutarán **en cuanto el navegador la vea**. Si están en otro archivo, cuando el navegador decida ejecutarlo (cuando *le toque*). En eso, son exactamente iguales a cualquier otro código Javascript.

¿ Para que sirve pasarle `window` y `document` ? Puede servirte para detectar si estas en un navegador en *ES5*, como módulo en *ES6*, o si estás en Node.js. Dependiendo de donde estés, recibirás unos u otros valores para `window` y `document`.

Por ejemplo, en *Node.js*, *ambas* serán *undefined*. En *ES5*, apuntarán a las globales correctas. En *ES6*, `window` será `undefined`, pero `document` no.

Comment: gracias por la explicacion, me aclaraste algunas cosas y otras no, como  , 'para que me sirve tener window y document' como parametros(para que los podria usar), asi como tambien si la IIFE se ejecuta antes o despues que carga el documento, y si recibo undefined o no

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Editado. Del último párrafo, los valores recibidos en distintos *ambientes*, **no estoy 100% seguro**, pero creo que es así.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a entender un poco las funciones para que quede un poco más claro.

En javascript tenemos las "function declaration" que son las funciones que se declaran con la palabra reservada function y un nombre

```
function miFuncion(parametro){...}
```

Tambien tenemos las "function expression" que normalmente conocemos como funciones anónimas

```
var miFuncion = function(parametro){....}; //Creamos la funcion
miFuncion(algunValor); //La ejecutamos
```

Esta última es la que se usa como auto ejecutable (IIFE) encerrando entre parentesis la declaración de la función y poniendo enseguida, entre parentesis, los valores que se le van a pasar a la funcion anónima, si se ponen los parentesis vacíos obviamente la estamos ejecutando sin parametros.

La función anónima anterior quedaría asi:

```
(function(parametro){...})(algunValor);
```

```js
var algunValor = 10;

 console.log("Mi valor original es: " + algunValor);
 
  (function(parametro){ parametro += 20; console.log("Dentro de la funcion anonima vale: " + parametro); } )(algunValor);
  
  console.log("Mi valor original fuera de la funcion anonima es: " + algunValor);
```

Para responder la pregunta de ¿cómo recibe los parametros la función?

```
(function(window, document){  })(window, document);
```

Vamos a escribirla de éste modo, que es comun encontrar para reducir el tamaño de un script

```
(function(w, d){  })(window, document);
```

Nuestra función anónima nos pide dos variables w y d y le estamos pasando como valores window y document del ámbito global respectivamente.
De esa forma podemos ocupar solo la variable **d** dentro de nuestra función anónima y no document, asi el peso del archivo será menor

```
(function(w, d){ d.getElementById('elemento');  })(window, document);
```

Otra razón por la que se usa window y document enviados como parametros es por que javascript maneja mejor las variables locales que las globales teniendo un mejor performance tu script, sin embargo solo se va a notar si tienes script muy complejos con muchas llamadas a window y document.

Las funciones IIFE se auto ejecutan cuando el explorador encuentra la línea donde está esa función, si buscas un elemento del DOM en la función anónima antes de que se cargue el árbol DOM seguro no lo encontrará, pero si ejecutas tu funcion al final de tu documento ya vas a tener tu árbol DOM completo.

Ahora, no confundas el árbol DOM con los objetos window y document ya que éstos últimos se crean al crear cualquier ventana y el árbol DOM se termina de crear cuando se lee todo el documento HTML. Entonces no importa donde ejecutes tun función anónima siempre vas a tener los objetos window y document listos.

Comment: Te dejo una liga de como hacer bien las cosas en javascript y una de ellas es el uso de la funcion IIFE pasandole window y document http://garystorey.com/2015/07/10/whats-wrong-with-your-javascript/